# Google Maps api: Polyline path

Tags: google-maps-api-3

```
var symbolOne = {
  path: 'M -2,0 0,-2 2,0 0,2 z',
  strokeColor: '#F00',
  fillColor: '#F00',
  fillOpacity: 1
};
```

This one is working perfect,  But I don't know what does 'M -2,0 0,-2 2,0 0,2 z' means, and what it will do.  Please someone help me to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Symbols)

```
M -2,0 0,-2 2,0 0,2 z'
```

is [SVG path notation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData)